# Join 2 MySQL tables into one using fuzzy match

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL table that I need to merge/join in one table.

Both tables has many columns and I need to merge the second table to the first one based on fuzzy match of two columns (name and address)

Here are what I have tried so far

```
UPDATE `table_one` 
Inner JOIN `table_two` ON (SOUNDEX(`table_two.name`) = SOUNDEX(`table_one.name`))
    AND (SOUNDEX(`table_two.address`) = SOUNDEX(`table_one.address`));
```

I need to have one final table_one with all fuzzy match from table_two merged with it based on the match.

Comment: update your question add  a data sample and the expcted  result

Comment: You are using an `UPDATE` query, but does not have any `SET` part? What are you trying to update (with what values)?